# How to save the entered text in blackberry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-cascades

How to save the entered text in blackberry 10. I'm planning to save it to stackmob by saving it using the submit/send key of the keypad

```
TextField {
                            id: tfComment
                            hintText: qsTr("add comment")
                            inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Text
                            input {
                                submitKey: SubmitKey.Submit
                                onSubmitted: {
                                }
                            }
```

What should i add on the submitkey and on the cpp?

Answer (score 0):

Within the `onSubmitted` slot, you should call a C++ [invokable](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/) function, with `text` as parameter. Your C++ function should take a `QVariant`, which will contain the string typed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You want to save it to cloud ? or just in local device ?

For local device you can use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html), its quite easy and useful.

For internet, you can pass entered data from QML to c++ by first exposing C++ object to QML.
and then calling appropriate API with parameter.

You can expose C++ object to QML by following code

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(&app);
FileModel fileModel;
qml->setContextProperty("fileModel", &fileModel);
```

Now your QML code will be able to use fileModel instance by fileModel name and you can call its public slot method or Invokable method from QML